# call multiple ajax in same event one after another (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, ajax

when i register a click event for a certain button (in Javascript) i want to do three ajax calls one after another.They modify server database correctly, but changes are not shown  well in the page.
I noticed that if I try click the button with inspector opened in debugging from chrome, page shows changes correctly. I think that it might be a conflict problem of the callback functions of ajax calls, but i don't know how to handle it.

Here is the code of the handling click event

```js
    document.getElementById("addCategory").addEventListener('click', (e) => {

            tree.autoclick();
            
            var form = document.getElementById("addcategoryform")
            if (form.checkValidity()) {
                makeCall("POST", 'AddCategory', e.target.closest("form"),
                    function (x) {
                        if (x.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                            var message = x.responseText;
                            switch (x.status) {
                                case 200:
                                    document.getElementById("erroradd").textContent = message;
                                    document.getElementById("erroradd").style.color = "green";
                                    break;
                                case 400: // bad request
                                    document.getElementById("erroradd").textContent = message;
                                    document.getElementById("erroradd").style.color = "red";
                                    break;
                                case 401: // unauthorized
                                    document.getElementById("erroradd").textContent = message;
                                    document.getElementById("erroradd").style.color = "red";
                                    break;
                                case 500: // server error
                                    document.getElementById("erroradd").textContent = message;
                                    document.getElementById("erroradd").style.color = "red";
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
            tree.show();
        }


    )
```

For first tree.autoclick simulates a click event of another button:

```js
      this.autoclick = function(){
         var e = new Event("click");
         this.saveButton.dispatchEvent(e);
            
        }
```

which do an ajax POST call, for saving on the server modifies  done client side with the  tree:

```js
  saveButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                makeCallParam("POST", 'saveModifies', from, to,
                    function (x) {
                        if (x.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                            let json = x.responseText;

                            switch (x.status) {
                                case 200:
                                    document.getElementById("message").textContent = json;
                                    document.getElementById("message").style.color = "green";
                                    break;
                                case 400: // bad request
                                    document.getElementById("message").textContent = json;
                                    document.getElementById("message").style.color = "red";
                                    break;
                                case 401: // unauthorized
                                    document.getElementById("messaggio").textContent = json;
                                    document.getElementById("messaggio").style.color = "red";
                                    break;
                                case 500: // server error
                                    document.getElementById("messaggio").textContent = json;
                                    document.getElementById("messaggio").style.color = "red";
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );

                
            })
```

after autoclick function, i do the ajax call for the originally click event(addCategory) that modifies also the tree on the server

For last, i call the tree function show() that request the tree modified with new categories with a GET ajax call and calls a function update() to print them on the html. The show() function doesn't work only when i do this action, in other cases shows correctly the tree as is it is in the server

```js
   show = function() {
            var self = this;
            makeCall("GET", "requestCategories", null,
                function(req) {
                    if (req.readyState == 4) {
                        var message = req.responseText;
                        if (req.status == 200) {
                            categoriesToShow = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                            if (categoriesToShow.length == 0) {
                                self.alert.textContent = "No categories yet!";
                                return;
                            }
                            self.update(mostraCategorie, document.getElementById("list")); // function that prints list of categories in "list"
                          

                        } else if (req.status == 403) {
                            window.location.href = req.getResponseHeader("Location");
                            window.sessionStorage.removeItem('username');
                        }
                        else {
                            self.alert.textContent = message;
                        }}
                }
            );
        };
```